# A method designed to chop a tileset into an array fails when it's given more then one row?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tile

This is the method in question:

```
Color[][] ChopUpTiles()
{
    int numTilesPerRow = terrainTiles.width / tileResolution;
    int numRows = terrainTiles.height / tileResolution;

    Color[][] tiles = new Color[numTilesPerRow * numRows][];

    for (int y = 0; y < numRows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numTilesPerRow; x++)
        {
            tiles[y * numTilesPerRow + x] = terrainTiles.GetPixels(x * tileResolution , y * tileResolution, tileResolution, tileResolution);

        }
    }

    return tiles;
}
```

It's a pretty basic function, and works - as long as the tileset in question only has one row. If it has more then a single row, it freaks out. Suddenly, using "tiles[1]" no longer returns tile 1. Instead, it returns... tile 15. I have no idea why it's acting this way, or where the math is wrong. Can someone spot what's going on?

Comment: In use, the function is used somewhat like this - which I meant to add but forgot earlier:   Color[][] tiles = ChopUpTiles(); - Color[] p = tiles[0];

Answer (score 1):

Don't you mean `tiles[y][numTilesPerRow + x]` or `tiles[y][x]` or something along those lines? because i don't know what you are trying to do, but you are retrieving an entire row not a tile itself.

also, i think `Color[][] tiles = new Color[numTilesPerRow * numRows][];` should be `Color[][] tiles = new Color[numRows][numTilesPerRow];` or am i wrong?

Basically, you have a multi-dimensional `Array` yet you are treating it as a single-dimensional `Array`

Comment: The original function isn't mine so I'd love some tips on how to fix it right. I was noticing that too and wondering if that was part of the problem.

Comment: i don't really understand exactly what it is trying to achieve to be honest, but i personally don't use 2 dimensional `Array`s i prefer to put everything into a single array that way queries can be achieved with a single loop and i don't have to have nested loops. For a 1 dimensional array, all you have to do is loop over all objects and use a modulus operation like such: `column = i % width` and `row = i % height`